# Column-count issue: Position absolute elements appear on the first column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm intended to use masonry with the usage of `column-count` in CSS. I understand there are more simpler solution such as create multiple columns for the masonry structure, but due to project's complication from PHP laravel, I needed to use only `column-count` in CSS when calling out the images.

This is the issue that I'm currently facing:
[image]

As you can see, due to `column-count: 3` the `position: absolute` item which is the cross button are now shown in half in the previous column. I've tried

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
                 break-inside: avoid;
```

but nothing changes.

Below are the related CSS code and HTML codes:

```
<div class="card-columns">
                @if ($gallery_images->isNotEmpty())
                    @foreach ($gallery_images as $gallery)
                        <div class="card">
                            {{-- <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $gallery->url }}"> --}}
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $gallery->url }}">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
                                    @if(Auth::user()->user_type_id != 3)
                                    {{-- <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i> --}}
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
                                    @endif
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </div>

.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.card-columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-columns .card {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.card-img, .card-img-top, .card-img-bottom {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.preview-remove-btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -16px;
    right: -2px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @MEMYSELF, still haveing the problem ?

Comment: My apologies upon the late response, unfortunately the problem still persists under the changes, and I've discussed and changed the layout pattern due to this complication. Hopefully there will be someone able to solve this issue and I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this problem add a `margin-top` to your card:

```
/** CSS Added **/
.card{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

### DEMO based on [BS 4.5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-columns):

```css
.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.card-columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-columns .card {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.card-img, .card-img-top, .card-img-bottom {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.preview-remove-btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -16px;
    right: -2px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/** CSS Added **/
.card{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="preview-remove-btn" href="{{ route('delete_gallery_image',$gallery->id) }}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash close font-size-12 text-danger"></i>
          <i class="mdi mdi-close-circle preview-remove-btn-icon"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```